# Usage of type-level method in swift

Tags: swift

I just know for type-level method, in class we should use *class* and in struct or enum should use *static*. But... let's see my example(My Xcode version is 6.3 beta 5),

```
class manager:NSObject{
   var type:NSDictionary?
   var array = NSMutableArray()

   class func start(types:NSDictionary){
       if array.count == 0 {...}
       self.type = types
   }
}
```

I will get errors in the type-level method **start**:

```
'start.Type' does not have a member named 'array'
```

and

```
'start.Type' does not have a member named 'type'
```

So, what's the correct usage? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? It is not obvious from your example.

In any case, a common usage of class level functions are accessors to singletons (such as [`sharedApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIApplication/sharedApplication) in UIApplication)

Here is an example how you could implement such method:

```
private var _sharedManager = Manager()

class Manager {
    class func sharedManager() -> Manager {
        return _sharedManager
    }
}
```

Note that as Swift 1.1 doesn't support class level variables yet, module level private variables are typically used to store data for class level functions.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Actually, I want a HTTPRequestManager to control my http requests, and I have found the right way, no use of class, just struct is ok, and I can use the 'static' to finish what I want. Thanks anyway